# Expanding DIV with background images

Tags: html, css

I have a slightly unusual requirement, which I am really struggling with. I have created an image to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Basically this is a DIV that is made up of 3 areas - top, middle and bottom. All 3 areas have background images and I need the middle area (the blue bit including its borders) to expand with the content. So the more content there is the bigger the middle area will be. The problem is that the content actually needs to cover the whole of the DIV and not just the middle area.

This is what I have at the moment:

HTML:

```
<div id="panel">
    <div id="top"></div>

    <div id="middle">
        <div id="content">
            Lorem ipsum, etc...
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#panel {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

#top {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(top.png) no-repeat;
}

#middle {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    background: url(middle.png) repeat-y;
}

#bottom {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(bottom.png) no-repeat;
}
```

This doesn't really work and is probably the incorrect approach. Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: you could just set the middle background on the panel i guess?

Comment: I think I tried that, the problem is the border on the middle area is different to the top and bottom areas, so it overlaps.

Comment: Are the borders part of the background image?

Comment: you can add a gradient to transparent that there is a more fluent transition, maybe you create a jsfiddle if i understood you wrong?
here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/5dvgk/2/

Comment: Yes the borders are part of the background image. They cannot be substituted for a CSS style.

Comment: sorry, updated the url: http://jsfiddle.net/5dvgk/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content will *never* cover everything because it's *inside* the middle panel, and the middle one is positioned to never take up the entire `#panel` - move the `#content` to be in the `#panel` element...

```
<div id="panel">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
    <div id="content">
        Lorem ipsum, etc...
    </div>
</div>
```

Position `#middle` using `position: absolute;` like `#top` and `#bottom`:

```
#panel {
    height: 400px; /* or 100% or whatever */
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

#top,
#middle,
#bottom {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

#top {
    height: 100px;
    background: url(top.png) no-repeat;
    top: 0;
}

#middle {
    bottom: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    background: url(middle.png) repeat-y;
}

#bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(bottom.png) no-repeat;
}

#content {
/* any padding or anything */
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trolleymusic/yqure/

Comment: This is the correct answer! It works exactly how I need it to! Such a simple solution! I will continue to test this and let you know how it goes. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

i would do it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/5dvgk/5/

html:

```
    <div id="middle">
        <div id="content">
            Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
            Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
            Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
            Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
            Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
            Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
            Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
            Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
            Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
            Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#panel {
    width: 330px;
    position: relative;
    background: url(http://oi44.tinypic.com/acoeo.jpg);
}

#top {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 170px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(http://oi43.tinypic.com/2zedqqc.jpg)
}

#middle {   
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}

#bottom {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 170px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(http://oi43.tinypic.com/34i0jeu.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this actually works very well. However there is one problem in that the borders actually contain transparent drop shadows, so the `#panel` background image is still visible underneath `#top` and `#bottom`. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a content area separate from what I would call the background area

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5dvgk/2/

Do something like this:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="background">
        <div class="top">
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Your content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

and your CSS would be something like this

```
.panel {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
.background {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.top {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(top.png) no-repeat;
    z-index: 2;
}
.middle {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(bottom.png) no-repeat;
    z-index: 2;
}
.content {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

Comment: same effect if you use the container as middle background and the middle part as content, just with less html :)

Comment: But the OP needs the .content to span the entire thing, not just the middle content.

Comment: And what about the background image for the middle content?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the other answers there are actually multiple ways to do this.

I decided to go with pure CSS and a little bit of element "scooting" with position:relative. Also, this method won't work unless the middle content box's background image is transparent in the content area.

I also removed some of the unnecessary floats and position absolutes, as these boxes can just stack on top of each other:

**Check out this fiddle, I tested it in IE9/FF/Chrome, but I'm sure it'll work at least down to IE6, as I've used this method before.**
http://jsfiddle.net/shayl/KwWjt/1/

[image]

I had to make an assumption about your middle content box and how you wanted it to look, but I used a background image.

---

CSS

---

```
            #panel {
                width: 234px;
            }

            #top {
                height:49px;
                background: url(http://s7.postimg.org/f1usobsnf/top.gif) no-repeat;
                z-index:1;
            }

            #middle {
                position:relative;
                top:-20px;
                width: 134px;
                min-height: 200px;
                padding:0 50px 0 50px;
                background: url(http://s23.postimg.org/gups2v0wb/mid.gif) repeat-y;
                z-index:2;
            }

            #bottom {
                position:relative;
                top:-30px;
                height:49px;
                width: 100%;
                background: url(http://s12.postimg.org/s78huz5u5/bottom.gif) no-repeat;
                z-index:1;
            }
```

---

HTML

---

```
            <div id="panel">
                <div id="top"></div>

                <div id="middle">
                    <div id="content">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quis condimentum lacus. Duis tempor bibendum ante, non luctus leo mollis vitae. Nunc in augue massa, ut facilisis velit. Etiam in magna lacus, in lacinia lectus. Nulla facilisi. Aenean rutrum, magna sed molestie condimentum, magna arcu ornare nisl, id luctus turpis felis ornare lorem. Aenean placerat erat in nisi convallis feugiat. Ut sodales tincidunt tellus, nec eleifend ligula posuere nec. Proin sit amet quam quam, mollis laoreet diam. Sed volutpat libero et velit commodo laoreet. Vestibulum eros dui, hendrerit molestie sodales eget, ullamcorper sed enim. Integer tempus, eros at dapibus ultricies, mauris risus sagittis metus, quis consequat massa mi quis felis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam sagittis blandit odio, sed vulputate quam egestas id. 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="bottom"></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In [most newer browsers which support parts of the CSS3 specification](http://caniuse.com/multibackgrounds) you can do this quite easily using [CSS3 multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds), if you need to support older browsers, then your current approach isn't too bad, you would need to absolutely position your top and bottom `div`s as you have already done, and then ensure the top and bottom `div`'s render behind the `div` in the middle by setting the `position` property (`z-index` doesn't work if `position` is not set) and then specifically setting their `z-index`.

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eBazG/1/)</kbd> demonstrating both approaches side by side. The one on the left is using CSS3 multiple backgrounds, the other one is a fixed up version of the approach you had going already.

**HTML**

```
<div id="css3-multiple-backgrounds">Content goes here..</div>

<div id="any-browser-not-using-css3">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div>Content goes here..</div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#css3-multiple-backgrounds {
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6928212/dots.png) left top no-repeat,        
                url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6928212/dots.png) left bottom no-repeat,
                url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6928212/bg.png) center center repeat-y;
}
#any-browser-not-using-css3 {
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6928212/bg.png) center center repeat-y;
    position: relative;
}
#any-browser-not-using-css3 > div {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
#any-browser-not-using-css3 > div[class] {
    position:absolute;
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6928212/dots.png) left top no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#any-browser-not-using-css3 > div.top {
    top: 0px;
}
#any-browser-not-using-css3 > div.bottom {
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the options above require fairly complex HTML / CSS. Here is an example that requires only two `DIV` tags and some CSS.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="border">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
    Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
    Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
    Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
    Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
    Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
    Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
    Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
    Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
    Lorem ipsum, etc...<br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.border { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 234px;
    background: #fff url(http://i41.tinypic.com/axzj0o.jpg) top center repeat-y;
}
.border:before, .border:after {
    position: absolute; 
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 53px; width: 234px;
}
.border:before {
    top: 0; left: 0;
    background: transparent url(http://i41.tinypic.com/2jgwn6.jpg) top center no-repeat;
}
.border:after {
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background: transparent url(http://i43.tinypic.com/vfiiag.jpg) bottom center no-repeat;
}
.border > .content { 
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    padding: 13px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This solution works by simply having 3 overlapping graphics, as shown below:

1. Background

   [image: Background]
2. Top

   [image: Top]
3. Bottom

   [image: Bottom]

The Background image is applied to the outer `DIV`, `.border`, and is allowed to `repeat-y` (repeat vertically along the `y` axis). The Top image is applied to the `:before` pseudo-element, and the Bottom image is applied to the `:after` pseudo-image.

Next, the `.content` `DIV`, `:before` and `:after` elements are all `position`ed so that they can have `z-index` applied. Because `:before` and `:after` are `position: absolute`, they no longer take up space in the flow - and therefore they do not affect the positioning of `.content` or each other.

This means that the `.content` inner-`DIV` will flow within its parent on its own, filling to the corners of `.border`.

However, it still needs to be given a `z-index: 1` in order to appear in front of the `:before` and `:after` elements - which completes the effect.

As you can see, I took the liberty of photoshopping your specific images so that you can see it working. Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image: Result]

And here is a [jsFiddle which demonstrates it working](https://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/ucRWD/).

Comment: This looks like a very good solution but will probably not work as expected when viewed on less capable browsers such as IE. Thank you for taking the time to produce this solution :)

Comment: Actually - I have tested it in IE10 in Standards/Quirks mode all the way back to IE7 and it works correctly in all of the above, and renders identically to Chrome/Firefox. The only time it should break down at all is in versions of IE which don't support `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements (such as 6). Other than that, every bit of this CSS has been around for over a decade and is completely standard in all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is this can precisely done with pure CSS, but I'd do it like that :

Set up your 3 areas, and add a push :

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="top"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="push"></div>
  <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Remove the content from the flow :

```
#content { position: absolute; }
```

and compute the push height :

```
h = $("#content").height() * 0.5;
$("#push").css( { "height": h } );
```

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RM9NS/1/

Answer (score 0):

If your willing to try css3 you can apply multiple backgrounds to the same tag.  Although you have to be careful as stretching images with distinct features like your stars above may become distorted using this method.

I played with an example.  While it doesn't seem to give me exactly what I was looking for I came close to what you're talking about. This would be great on images that are gradient based and have no distinct features.  However, any image stretched too far will always lead to pixelation.  Most css I've seen of this variety creates a 1px wide gradient of 'so much' length.  Stretching elements like these is harder to see pixelation in.

```
<html>
<head>
 <style>
#container {
background: url(red.jpg) no-repeat, 
            url(checkered.jpg) no-repeat, 
            url(purple.jpg) no-repeat;

background-position: 0 0 , 0 20%, 0 100%;
background-size: 100% 20%, 100% 80%, 100% 20%;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To avoid the problem of stretched top/bottom images, could you not simply use a defined px instead of a percentage for the size?

Answer (score 0):

See this: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5dvgk/6/)

You can adjust the `margin` and set `display: inline-block; width: --px;` if you want.

**EDIT**

After reading the question again, I came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/5dvgk/7/

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just try to append the three images into one image file.  This way you only need one div and no tricky styling.

Comment: Ah, but then the top and bottom images will stretch with the content.